# snakemake error: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'batch'

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I don't understand how to redefine my snakemake rule to fix the Wildcards issue below.

Ignore the logic of batches, it internally makes sense in the python script. In theory, I want the rule to be run for each batch 1-20. I use BATCHES list for {batch} in output, and in the shell command, I use {wildcards.batch}:

```
OUTDIR="my_dir/"
nBATCHES = 20
BATCHES = list(range(1,21)) # [1,2,3 ..20] list

[...]

rule step5:
    input:
        ids = expand('{IDLIST}', IDLIST=IDLIST)
    output:
        type1 = expand('{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type1.csv.gz', OUTDIR=OUTDIR, batch=BATCHES),
        type2 = expand('{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type2.csv.gz', OUTDIR=OUTDIR, batch=BATCHES),
        type3 = expand('{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type3.csv.gz', OUTDIR=OUTDIR, batch=BATCHES)
    shell:
        "./some_script.py --outdir {OUTDIR} --idlist {input.ids}  --total_batches {nBATCHES} --current_batch {wildcards.batch}"
```

Error:

```
RuleException in rule step5  in line 241 of Snakefile:

AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'batch', when formatting the following:

./somescript.py --outdir {OUTDIR} --idlist {input.idlist}  --totalbatches {nBATCHES} --current_batch {wildcards.batch}
```

Executing script for a single batch manually looks like this (and works): (total_batches is a constant; current_batch is supposed to iterate)

`./somescript.py --outdir my_dir/ --idlist ids.csv --total_batches 20 --current_batch 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to run the `rule step5` once for each `batch` in `BATCHES`. So you need to structure your `Snakefile` to do exactly that.

In the following `Snakefile` running the `rule all` runs your `rule step5` for all combinations of `OUTDIR` and `BATCHES`:

```py
OUTDIR = "my_dir"
nBATCHES = 20
BATCHES = list(range(1, 21))  # [1,2,3 ..20] list
IDLIST = ["a", "b"] # dummy data, I don't have the original

rule all:
    input:
        type1=expand(
            "{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type1.csv.gz",
            OUTDIR=OUTDIR,
            batch=BATCHES,
        ),


rule step5:
    input:
        ids=expand("{IDLIST}", IDLIST=IDLIST),
    output:
        type1="{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type1.csv.gz",
        type2="{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type2.csv.gz",
        type3="{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type3.csv.gz",
    shell:
        "./some_script.py --outdir {OUTDIR} --idlist {input.ids}  --total_batches {nBATCHES} --current_batch {wildcards.batch}"
```

In your earlier version `{batches}` was just an `expand`-placeholder, but not a wildcard and the rule was only called once.

Instead of the `rule all`, this could be a subsequent rule which uses one or multiple of the outputs generated from `step5`.

Comment: This worked! Getting rid of expand() in output, and adding an extra step to check all outputs are present. Thanks! 
For others FYI this is my extra step: 
rule check_step5:
    input:
      expand('{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type1.csv.gz', OUTDIR=OUTDIR, batch=BATCHES),
      expand('{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type2.csv.gz', OUTDIR=OUTDIR, batch=BATCHES),
      expand('{OUTDIR}/resources/{batch}_output_type3.csv.gz', OUTDIR=OUTDIR, batch=BATCHES)
    
    output:
        expand('{OUTDIR}/resources/flag_step5_checked', OUTDIR=OUTDIR)
    shell:
        "touch {output}"